# A big ReactiveVar with many keys or a big Hash with many ReactiveVars?

Tags: meteor

For example,

```
var settingsA = new ReactiveVar({
  a: {
    b : true,
    c : 1
  },
  d: true,
})

var settingsB = {
  a: {
    b: new ReactiveVar(true),
    c: new ReactiveVar(1),
  },      
  d: new ReactiveVar(true),
}
```

Which one is better? For settingA, it is difficult to update only one field.

What is the best practise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where possible, the second example is better, as it has more fine-grained reactivity.

Using the first example:

```js
var auto1 = Tracker.autorun(function () {
    doSomethingWith(settingsA.get().a.b);
});

var auto2 = Tracker.autorun(function () {
    doSomethingElseWith(settingsA.get().d);
});
```

If you do

```js
var old = settingsA.get();
old.d = 5;
settingsA.set(old);
```

Then both `auto1` and `auto2` will be re-run, even though the data accessed by `auto1` was not changed.

On the other hand, using the second example:

```js
var auto1 = Tracker.autorun(function () {
    doSomethingWith(settingsB.a.b.get());
});

var auto2 = Tracker.autorun(function () {
    doSomethingElseWith(settingsB.d.get());
});
```

Doing `settingsB.d.set(5)` will only cause `auto2` to re-run, and not `auto1`.

Now if the keys in the hash are inserted and removed dynamically, the second case might not be possible. In this case, you should consider using a `ReactiveDict`.